# Announcement is null when queried on feedItem Trigger

Tags: community, feeditem, chatter-feed, chatter-groups

When i try to fetch announcements from feedItem trigger it returns null always, is there anything i'm missing

```
trigger Email_Feed_Trigger on FeedItem (after insert) {   
Set<Id> myfeed=new set<Id>();

for(FeedItem item : Trigger.New)
{
    myfeed.add(item.Id);
    }
    List<Announcement> lst=  [select id,SendEmails,FeedItemId,ParentId,createddate from Announcement where FeedItemId IN:myfeed];
   //lst is always blank
    system.debug(lst);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will not get the announcement record because the- announcement has a relation to feed item which is required field on the announcement object. So, once feed item gets inserted then only announcement records will get inserted.

Understand the whole process with this: Creating a group announcement is a three-step process.

1. Use the FeedItem object to create a text post with the
   announcement’s content. Use the CollaborationGroup record you want
   to post the announcement to as the parent of this feed item.
2. Next, use the feed item ID and an expiration date to create the
   announcement record.
3. Finally, update the AnnouncementId field in the CollaborationGroup
   record with the ID of the announcement you created.

Note:- You cannot write a trigger on Announcement object.

Comment: You can see i'm using after insert trigger? so announcement record must be available at that point, i know we cant write trigger on Announcement object thats why i'm doing it on feedItem